# The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it with remember me authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-mybatis

i'm trying to implement persistent token remember me authentication in spring security and i am calling a controller (/test) from postman,
but when i put in my security-config.xml file the following line :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/testt" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

i get the following error in postman directly after i hit the send button:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status [403] – [Forbidden]</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status [403] – [Forbidden]</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Access Denied</p><p><b>Description</b> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.15</h3></body></html>
```

my security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="entryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/testt" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginTest" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
        <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="testKeyForBlog" />
    </http>

    <!-- Authentication Manager (uses same UserDetailsService as RememberMeService) -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>



    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <!-- <beans:bean name="userServiceSec" class="com.equadis.webapp.service.UserServiceSec"/> -->
</beans:beans>
```

any help please?

Comment: first of all, show you spring security configuration. btw, have you installed "postman interceptor"?

Comment: @Dmitry Senkovich thank you replying , i've added my spring security configuration in the example above and actually no i haven't installed "postman interceptor" , is it necessary?

Comment: also, what url is configured in you app? I see `/test` and `/testt`

Comment: You also have annotations for security, I suspect you have somewhere `fullyAuthenticated` in a security expression.

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich sorry it was a typing mistake that i've updated , it's /testt

Comment: @M.Deinum can you explain what do you mean ? and thank you for your reply

Comment: You have global method security enabled and enabled secured annotations. So I suspect you have a expression somewhere that requires full authentication (which means authenticated with username/passwrod instead of remember me). I also wonder how are you authenticating? I see no basic or form login configured.

Comment: @M.Deinum this annotation is an old one i guess that i was using for basic authentication , i've removed it now and actually i have no login form , i'm using postman to test it.is a login form needed?can you provide me with a clear example for remember me authentication?i am trying to do an api and want to test it without a form if it is possible.thank you a lot again

Comment: If you want to use remember me you also need to have a means to authenticate. Apparently you haven't.